# testNG annotation which would equal to "finally" in java?

Tags: java, testing, annotations, testng

i don't know if my question was clear, but i am using testNG and i have this:

```
@Test
public void passengerServiceTest() {
...
}

@AfterTest
public void deleteCreatedPassenger() {
...    
}
```

I want to execute my deleteCreatedPassenger() method after passengerServiceTest, also, i want that in case of deleteCreatedPassenger fails, passengerServiceTest fails too, in other words, i want that both of them be the same test, so if one them fails, test fails. 
So i tried with the annotations @AfterTest, @AfterMethod, @AfterClass and all make two tests as "separated" tests.
Do you know how to do this? Regards

Comment: i put that equals to finally because before using annotations, i had the delete method into finally inside passengerServiceTest, and i want the same functionality but with annotations

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need annotations to achieve this, since it's exactly what the finally block is intended for:

```
@Test
public void passengerServiceTest() {            
    try {
        //test code 
    } finally {
        deleteCreatedPassenger();
    }
}

public void deleteCreatedPassenger() {
...    
}
```

If the delete throws an exception then your service test fails.

Annotations are useful in certain scenarios, you shouldn't aim to use them over core language constructs.

Comment: yes, i had this like this before, but i was trying to avoid  the try and finally. I want to do exactly the same but with annotations , is that possible ? Thanks you !

Comment: I think it's neither possible nor desirable!  'try - finally' is a fine, well used and understood concept.

Comment: Ok! thanks for your help! I am doing this like your way

Answer (score 0):

`alwaysRun`
https://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html

Ex:

```
@AfterTest(alwaysRun = true)
public void deleteOldValuesFromDatabase() {
    ...
}
```

Docs say that this will cause the method to run "even if one or more methods invoked previously failed or was skipped"